# React: Add active class to selected Nav link on click

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add an 'active' class to a nav link when it is clicked.

in JQuery I could do something like:

```
$('.navlink').on('click', function() {
    $("a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

This is the closet I've managed to get in React:

```
export class NavLink extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleClass=this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isActive: 1,
    }
  }

toggleClass = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: this.props.id });
  }


render() {
    const { href, name, id } = this.props;
    const classNames = this.state.isActive === id ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link";

    return (
        <a 
        className={classNames} 
        onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this)} href={href}>{name}</a>
      )
  }
}
```

The problem is React only re-renders the clicked on link. So once a link has been given a class of active it won't be removed if a different link is clicked.

Comment: as opposed to having each navlink keep track of its own state, keep track of it higher up. can you post the parent component that renders these links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something like this in terms of components:

```
NavLinkList
|--NavLink
|--NavLink
```

`NavLinkList` would be the one holding the `activeLinkId` in its state.

That `activeLinkId` would then be passed to each `Link` as `prop` so when it is changed the Links would re-render.

Also in that `NavLinkList` you would have the function which would change the `activeLinkId` on the `Link`s `onClick` handler.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while took me to work out how to implement this (still pretty new to React), but this works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this before. It is easier to do this through the parent component. I didn't have components for each of my links. I just set their classes before the return in the render. Here is a sample of the code I did that I hope can be helpful to you.

I did the same thing with the onClick and the state just held a selected which held a String representing the name of the nav item. I had a Stories, Comments, and Likes nav links. Their original class was just 'tab'.

```
render () {
   let storiesClass = 'tab';
   let commentsClass = 'tab';
   let likesClass = 'tab';
   if (this.state.selected === "Stories") {
     storiesClass += 'Selected';
     commentsClass = 'tab';
     likesClass = 'tab';
   } else if (this.state.selected === "Comments") {
     storiesClass = 'tab';
     commentsClass += 'Selected';
     likesClass = 'tab';
   } else {
     storiesClass = 'tab';
     commentsClass = 'tab';
     likesClass += 'Selected';
   }

   return (
       <button className={storiesClass} onClick={this.selectTab("Stories")}>...
```