# Active class in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi I am using react router v6 and I use NavLink to navigate from one component to another component. I want to add custom active class in NavLink how can I achieve in react router v6.
I use this but its not working.

```
<NavLink className="px-3 py-2 bg-primary" to={"/"} activeClassName="btn-group-active" >
Home
</NavLink >
```

How to achieve above with react router v6.

I got my answer from this link.

[Active link with React-Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131450/active-link-with-react-router)

Comment: I refer to the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link) for react-router v6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Add active class to selected Nav link on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729059/react-add-active-class-to-selected-nav-link-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing that:

```
<NavLink
  to={customPath}
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "myCssClass" : "")}
>
  <Home />
</NavLink>
```

If you have further classes you concat them like that:

```
<NavLink
  to={customPath}
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "myActiveClass defaultClass defaultClassTwo" : "defaultClass")}
>
  <Home />
</NavLink>
```

Comment: But I have three to four classes how to concat active class with another class. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran Then store your classnames in a string inside your component and use the variable in the ternary operator.

Comment: But I use ternary operator and add function isActive in ${} but it does not working.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran I've made an edit to my post. Does this answer your question?

Comment: But if link is not active then default classA and classB also not work.

Comment: I get solution  and I edit my question